# How to turn a wired dimmer into a wireless one?

Tags: wireless, dimmer

I'm working on a personal project for residential automation. I want to make a **wireless** Arduino controlled dimmer. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit/?ALLSTEPS) and I made my dimmer, but it's wired.

Below is the circuit and the schematics (pictures are from the tutorial linked above).

[image: Wired dimmer]
[image]

What changes should I make to that circuit so that it can be actuated wirelessly?

Comment: Lots of ways you could go about this, most of which aren't specific to this project. For instance, you could add Bluetooth, WiFi, infrared, XBee,  or simple RF.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also an EE student. My senior project is similar to what you are doing. I would recommend:
1) choose a wireless standard. I used Bluetooth because it was part of the requirement. Good thing about bluetooth is its easy to use and has a relatively high bandwidth. Bad thing is that it is hard to broadcast your commands to multiple "slaves". Zigbee uses a mesh nextwork, and it allows you to do that, but Zigbee has a bandwidth restriction. 
2) choose a wireless module: look at microcontrollers with the wireless chips implemented. Put one on your arduino, and another one to the light. 
3) Program them. This requires you look up guides, read datasheets etc.

Comment: For this application I don't believe bandwidth would be a bottleneck.